# Java Collections API: missing a Sequence (ordered Collection) super-interface of List and Deque?

Tags: java, collections

I need to expose an API - `consume(sequence)` below - which mandates that its argument `sequence` collection be ordered as in the below excerpt:

```java
interface Consumer<T> {
    /**
     * @param sequence: an *ordered* collection of Ts to be processed in order
     */
    public void consume(Collection<T> sequence);
}

interface Producer<T> {
    Collection<T> getSequence();
}

class Producer1<T> implements Producer<T> {
    public List<T> getSequence() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
class Producer2<T> implements Producer<T> {
    public Deque<T> getSequence() {
        return new LinkedList<>();
    }
}

class Test {
    void testMethod(Consumer<Long> consumer) {
        consumer.consume(new Producer1<Long>().getSequence());
        consumer.consume(new Producer2<Long>().getSequence());
    }
}
```

Typically one would specify `consume()` as accepting a `List`; however, some producers also expose a `Deque`, so as to facilitate things like efficient reverse-iteration using `descendingIterator()`.  However `Deque` doesn't extend `List` and there are [likely good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44059003/645016) for this (O(n) cost of accessing an indexed element in a `LinkedList`).

So it seems the only way to "keep the compiler happy" is to specify `sequence` as a `Collection`; however, according to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) (and as we all know), a "some are ordered and others unordered", so the `consume()` API looses in semantics.

Another workaround would be to have `Producer2` expose a `LinkedList` rather than a `Deque` (and revert `consume()` to accept a `List`) but we know it's not ideal to expose implementations rather than interfaces.

It seems the ideal solution would be for Java to provide a `Sequence` super-interface to `List` and `Deque` (extending `Iterable`).  I can imagine one reason this wasn't done is complexity but I think this example demonstrates the need.

Am I missing a better strategy here or do I just need to wait for a revision of the API?  For the record, this is Java 17.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There just happened to be a discussion about this in the OpenJDK mailing list. You can find an archive here: https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2022-February/085683.html. That discussion mentions the new [*JEP draft: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8280836) launched this year, 2022-01.

Until that is resolved, I'm afraid you'll have to resort to documenting that the collections need to be ordered, and trusting that callers adhere to your precondition.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers.  Great to hear that I'm not the only one missing this feature and that it might get implemented at some point...  Amazing it's "only" taken some 15 years for this gap to be recognized.

Comment: @sxc731 your “15 years” looks very arbitrary. Either, you assume 24 years (since the introduction of the Collection API) or you assume 8 years (since the introduction of `default` methods which allow provide this feature later now without breaking compatibility).

Comment: @Holdger; I was referring to the introduction of the `Deque` in JDK 1.6; I suppose a `Sequence` super-interface to `Deque`and `List` could have been introduced at the same time without too much hassle?  Admittedly this would just address my simplistic use-case, not all the goodies from the JEP.

Answer (score 1):

[Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) API has already been integrated into JDK codebase and will be released along with JDK 21 on [September 19](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/21/), 2023.